# Undeclared type in enum while the declaration is in the same file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to make a simple data type for storing video or image + sound but i get a compilation error "Use of undeclared type" on the enum `MovieItem` and `ImageItem`. What is wrong?

```
struct MovieItem {
    let movieUrl: NSURL
}

struct ImageItem {
    let imageUrl: NSURL // UIImage?
    let soundUrl: NSURL
}

enum Item {
    case MovieItem(MovieItem) // Undeclared type: MovieItem
    case ImageItem(ImageItem) // Undeclared type: ImageItem
}
```

Comment: This is still an [open issue](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-169). If you don't want to rename your case or struct, there is a workaround. You can qualify the struct type name with the enclosing module. For example, if `struct MovieItem` is defined in module `MyModule`, you should be able to write the corresponding case as `case MovieItem(MyModule.MovieItem)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the compiler is confused by your use of `MovieItem` as the name of a `struct` and by its use as a `case` label inside of `Item`. If you change the name of the `case` label it should work:

```
struct MovieItem {
    let movieUrl: NSURL
}

struct ImageItem {
    let imageUrl: NSURL // UIImage?
    let soundUrl: NSURL
}

// Changed MovieItem to Movie and ImageItem to Image and it works
enum Item {
    case Movie(MovieItem)
    case Image(ImageItem)
}
```

Comment: That was the case, well spotted!

Comment: Is there a way around this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my old answer was bad. Roman has the right answer.

I'm updating it so it is correct now.

This doesn't produce an error

```
struct MovieItem {
    let movieUrl: NSURL
}

struct ImageItem {
    let imageUrl: NSURL // UIImage?
    let soundUrl: NSURL
}

enum Item {
    case Movie(MovieItem) 
    case Image(ImageItem) 
}
```

Comment: That looks cleaner, but it should work my way too right?

Comment: It looks cleaner, but it also doesn't have the associated value that I think the OP desires...

Comment: Yeah, is there a way to extract the urls (movie, image, sound) using this method?

Comment: It appears I was wrong, the other answer was right. I'll update mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a typealias (outside the enum) with different type names.
It results in a more obscure and confusing code in this case, but I left it here just to consider other options:

```
struct MovieItem {
    let movieUrl: NSURL
}

struct ImageItem {
    let imageUrl: NSURL // UIImage?
    let soundUrl: NSURL
}

typealias MovieItemType = MovieItem
typealias ImageItemType = ImageItem

enum Item {
    case MovieItem(MovieItemType)
    case ImageItem(ImageItemType)
}
```